# Salt Custom Grains - trying to return an empty 'list-type' grain

Tags: python, salt-stack

I want to have

`salt 'target' grains.items`

return a result with a grain, that is an empty list:

```
target:
     ...other grains...

     grain_name: 
        None

    ...other grains...
```

So, later, I can run this custom salt state and use salt.states.grains.append. My custom salt state (via a sls file, named grains_name_state.sls, in /srv/salt/_files) is as follows:

```
grain_name:
    grains.append:
        - value: whatever_value
```

My custom grains module (via a python file, named custom_grain.py, in /srv/salt/_grains on the master) is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def my_custom_grain():
    #initialize an empty grains list for the grain 'grain_name'
    grains = {}
    grains['grain_name'] = []
    return grains
```

So, calling 
`salt 'target' saltutil.sync_grains` should load the custom grain into the target minion. And then, `salt 'target' grains.items` should contain the results for the target and show the 'grains_name' value as None. But instead it contains this:

```
target:
    ...other grains...

    grain_name:

    ...other grains...
```

Then, when I try, `salt 'target' state.apply grains_name_state`, it yields a failure saying 'Comment: Grain grain_name does not exist'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; though, I am not sure why salt.states.list_append works when the grain should be a list-type and be append-able.
Working with Saltstack 2016.3.3+, my custom salt state (via a sls file, named grains_name_state.sls, in /srv/salt/_files) is as follows:

```
grain_name:
    grains.list_present:
        - value: whatever_value
```

Then, after the first highstate/state.apply, the grain_name grain is available to use list_present (a duplicate append command) on.